# Manage a tableView in another tableView in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I would like to manage a tableView in a first tableView. After hours of research for the good tools to use or example's to understand what to use I'm writing my post here as my last hope !

I use `UITableViewController` to manage my first table.
In a cell of this first table I have a label and another tableView.
So *how to give the control to the second table when I click on a cell of the first table?*

I want to stay on the same page when I click on a cell, I just want the new list appear under the cell selected and disappear if I click on again !

Thanks for any clue !

Zarof

Comment: I am assuming that you know what a UITableView is and how it is used. The outer tableView is in the UITableViewController's subclass and hence that class serves as the dataSource of outer tableview. The other tableView, as you say, is contained inside a cell of the outer tableView. So as a rule of thumb you should make your own class for the cell that contains the tableView and make that class the dataSource and delegate of the inner tableView. Then you can do whatever you want with either of the tableViews maintaining a distinction between them.

Comment: Mention not. What do you mean by 3 files?

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
If I understand well I will have 4 files:
1) ViewController where I declare my first table (number of section and describe a cell)
2) MyCustomCell which has details about the first level of cells (UILabel and a UITableView)
3)SubCellController which controls the second level of cells (number of section and describe a cell)
4)MySubCell which has details about the second level of cells (UILabel)

Am I write?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Apart from the storyboard and nibs you'll have only two swift files. 1) A subclass of UITableViewController that contains your outer tableView. 2) A subclass of UITableViewCell that has the inner tableView.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will try that :)

Comment: But my gut feeling tells me that this is not what you are looking for. Maybe you have a wrong approach to get what you want. From the question statement it looks like you want to show a list i.e, a tableView and when the user taps on any cell it should expand to show details in that particular cell. Is that correct?

Comment: But in which file I will put the information of my second table? I mean the number of section, the cell's info...? I can't call those methods in a UITableViewCell...

Comment: Yes, it's what I want. All I found is when I clicked on a cell it open a new page... What I want is like for a calendar. You have the list of days, and if you click on a day it appears the event's list for this day but you have still the day's list display ! Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Okay. Did you try the link given in the answer below? I think that is what you are looking for. Just have a look at it and let me know if it doesn't fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem...
The problem is that my second table is variable, sometimes I will have two rows, others three... And I have to link it with a second array (where datas are). I have to create a application that resume the schedule of a conference and when people click on a session they can see the details of the session which contains 2 or 3 sub-session !